# HANA JDBC Metadata

Tags: jdbc, metadata, union, hana

The HANA JDBC driver returns a different metadata type for a column when a union is performed even if both columns in the union have the same type.

Consider the case below :

```
create table test (
    A NCHAR(1),
    B NCHAR(1)
);

insert into test values('A','B');

select a from test union select b from test;
```

If I examine the metadata of the resultset, the type of the result column is NVARCHAR, not NCHAR as expected, event though both columns have the type NCHAR.

If however I run the query :

```
select a from test union select a from test;
```

the JDBC metadata returns the expected type NCHAR.

Other databases, notably Oracle do not behave like this. The JDBC type will be preserved over a UNION if both columns have the same type.

Below are the details of the JDBC driver I am using

```
Implementation-Title: SAP HANA JDBC Driver
Implementation-Vendor: SAP SE
Implementation-Version: 2.0.5-e130cbef291d3b62d5b138d3d5ce24e251013ac2
```

Any ideas on this?
Is there any way I can force the driver to preserve the type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I corrected it. If I select the same column in the UNION the JDBC type is preserved

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't know what driver version you're using. However, I suspect that this is due to HANA internal behavior since `(N)CHAR` are deprecated data types. In this case HANA correctly delivers the supported types `(N)VARCHAR`.

Comment: I have added details of the driver (please see above).

Comment: If I select the same column over a UNION the JDBC type will be preserved. In practice HANA supports (N)CHAR. To my knowledge there were initial plans to deprecate these types however they have been abandoned. If have searched for an official statement on this topic but have not found one. Can you send me a link or a document reference where it is officially stated that these JDBC types are deprecated.

Comment: The current documentation https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/a33f7884b0c14c00b1a76ecd8af5feca.html clearly states that the fixed-length character types are not supported and only retained for backward compatibility. The type coercion actually happens in the UNION operator (HANA server) not in the JDBC driver software. The query optimizer does understand that in your 2nd example it is dealing with the exact same column, so it does choose a different UNION implementation (UNION vs. MATERIALIZED UNION).